# Remove first 2 letters from workspace variables

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a .mat file and I know that each of the variables in it has `XY` in front of it (e.g. `XYJanuary`, `XYFebruary`, `XYMarch` and so on...) and I just want to remove the `XY`.

I have looked at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13143-rename-workspace-variables) and tried to copy it but this adds the `XY` to my variable (`XYXYJanuary`, `XYXYFebruay`,...) but I want it to be just (`January`, `Februay`,...).

```
x= load('file.mat');                             % Load into structure x
names=fieldnames(x);                             % names of the variables
  for iname=1:length(names)                      % start the loop 
    x.(['XY', names{iname}]) = x.(names{iname}); % PROBLEM
    x = rmfield(x, names{iname});
  end
save ('newfile.mat', '-struct', 'x');            %save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x= load('file.mat');                              % Load into structure x
names=fieldnames(x);                              % names of the variables
  for iname=1:length(names)                       % start the loop 
    x.([names{iname}(3:end)]) = x.(names{iname}); % No more PROBLEM
    x = rmfield(x, names{iname});
  end
save ('newfile.mat', '-struct', 'x');             % save
```

You added the `'XY'` to the LHS of your line, that makes it add it to the final solution. What I did is to chop off the first two entries, but keep the rest, hence the  `(3:end)`. This now works on a test case I created.

Comment: This works perfectly, but may I ask why you cannot use 'XY' on the RHS... 3:end is essentially the same thing... 

and doing x.([names{iname},('XY')]) puts the XY at the end of the variable....

Comment: You can, but it would *append*  `XY` to your data. This is therefore not the same thing, as you want to remove characters, not add them. Removing things have to be done through manipulation of indices, as I did here.